# OpenVPN not Routing correctly on CentOS 6

Tags: routing, openvpn, centos6

I am trying to set up OpenVPN 2.2.1 on my CentOS 6.2 VPS. This is my first time setting up, and everything went smoothly. The service is running, and the client is able to connect. My intention is to forward all my traffic from the client, to my VPS, to the internet. However, I am met with a problem.

When pinging the VPS IP, everything works fine. However, when pinging ANY other IP/name server on the internet, it refuses to connect.

I have spent the past 5 hours reading threads and looking for solutions, but none of them applied to me. The nature of the problem has led me to believe that it is an issue with the traffic not being routed correctly.

OpenVPN Server Config:

```
local 5.34.244.*** (asterisks applied for privacy)
port 443
proto tcp
dev tun
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/dh1024.pem
plugin /usr/share/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/login
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
server 1.2.4.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 4.2.2.1"
keepalive 5 30
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status server-tcp.log
verb 3
```

OpenVPN Client Config:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote 5.34.244.*** 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert sample.crt
key sample.key
comp-lzo
verb 3
route-method exe
route-delay 2
```

IPtables:

```
# iptables -L -t nat -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 6706 packets, 397K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 6406 packets, 377K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 2386  145K SNAT       all  --  any    any     1.2.4.0/24           anywhere            

to:5.34.244.***
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  any    any     1.2.4.0/24           anywhere            

to:5.34.244.***
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    eth0    1.2.4.0/24           anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5270 packets, 312K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

and

```
# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1377 packets, 415K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    4   216 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp 

dpt:87
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp 

dpt:87
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp 

dpt:87
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp 

dpt:87
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp 

dpt:87
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp 

dpt:87
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 140K packets, 3823K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

In my sysctl.conf file, I've enabled IP forwarding:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

I tried posting on the OpenVPN forums for support, but my thread got mysteriously deleted. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Adding reoccurring log entry from /var/log/messages (asterisks added for privacy):

```
Aug 11 03:53:27 vps openvpn[28055]: mac/**.233.229.93:50840 Need IPv6 code in mroute_extract_addr_from_packet
```

Edit:
Adding requested info:

```
# sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables" is an unknown key
error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables" is an unknown key
error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables" is an unknown key
```

-

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

-

```
# tcpdump -i tun0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 65535 bytes
05:24:30.574250 IP resolver1.opendns.com.domain > 1.2.4.6.62511: 20077 2/0/0 CNAME teredo.ipv6.microsoft.com.ns
atc.net., A 94.245.121.253 (108)
05:24:32.328193 IP a.resolvers.level3.net.domain > 1.2.4.6.62511: 20077 2/0/0 CNAME teredo.ipv6.microsoft.com.n
satc.net., A 65.55.158.118 (108)
05:24:34.027459 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com > 1.2.4.6: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 1242, length 40
05:24:37.848645 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com > 1.2.4.6: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 1243, length 40
05:24:38.729543 IP 63-225-240-44.hlrn.qwest.net.30160 > 1.2.4.6.51958: Flags [S.], seq 784307014, ack 187668555
9, win 14600, options [mss 1452,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 4], length 0
05:24:39.132105 IP 63-225-240-44.hlrn.qwest.net.30160 > 1.2.4.6.51960: Flags [S.], seq 3810646056, ack 33965940
38, win 14600, options [mss 1452,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 4], length 0
05:24:42.866762 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com > 1.2.4.6: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 1244, length 40
05:24:48.065918 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com > 1.2.4.6: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 1245, length 40
05:24:58.234720 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com > 1.2.4.6: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 1247, length 40
05:25:02.852886 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com > 1.2.4.6: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 1248, length 40

10 packets captured
10 packets received by filter
```

-

Client side log (asterisks for privacy):

```
Sat Aug 11 02:53:46 2012 OpenVPN 2.2.2 Win32-MSVC++ [SSL] [LZO2] [PKCS11] built on Dec 15 2011
Sat Aug 11 02:53:50 2012 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Sat Aug 11 02:53:50 2012 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Sat Aug 11 02:53:50 2012 LZO compression initialized
Sat Aug 11 02:53:50 2012 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1576 D:140 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Sat Aug 11 02:53:50 2012 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Sat Aug 11 02:53:50 2012 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1576 D:1450 EF:44 EB:135 ET:32 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Sat Aug 11 02:53:50 2012 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '2547efd2'
Sat Aug 11 02:53:50 2012 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '77cf0943'
Sat Aug 11 02:53:50 2012 Attempting to establish TCP connection with 5.34.244.***:443
Sat Aug 11 02:53:51 2012 TCP connection established with 5.34.244.***:443
Sat Aug 11 02:53:51 2012 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Sat Aug 11 02:53:51 2012 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: 5.34.244.***:443
Sat Aug 11 02:53:51 2012 TLS: Initial packet from 5.34.244.***:443, sid=41dd99fd d7cc097e
Sat Aug 11 02:53:51 2012 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Sat Aug 11 02:53:54 2012 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=Fort-Funston/OU=changeme/CN=macvpn/name=changeme/emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Sat Aug 11 02:53:54 2012 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=Fort-Funston/OU=changeme/CN=Build_Diffie_Hellman/name=changeme/emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Sat Aug 11 02:53:56 2012 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Sat Aug 11 02:53:56 2012 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 11 02:53:56 2012 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Sat Aug 11 02:53:56 2012 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 11 02:53:56 2012 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
Sat Aug 11 02:53:56 2012 [Build_Diffie_Hellman] Peer Connection Initiated with 5.34.244.***:443
Sat Aug 11 02:53:58 2012 SENT CONTROL [Build_Diffie_Hellman]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Sat Aug 11 02:53:59 2012 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222,dhcp-option DNS 4.2.2.1,route 1.2.4.1,topology net30,ping 5,ping-restart 30,ifconfig 1.2.4.6 1.2.4.5'
Sat Aug 11 02:53:59 2012 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Sat Aug 11 02:53:59 2012 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Sat Aug 11 02:53:59 2012 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Sat Aug 11 02:53:59 2012 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Sat Aug 11 02:53:59 2012 ROUTE default_gateway=192.168.1.1
Sat Aug 11 02:53:59 2012 TAP-WIN32 device [Local Area Connection 2] opened: \\.\Global\{3A817AE1-696B-4DEB-BD4F-8BE01F11FC47}.tap
Sat Aug 11 02:53:59 2012 TAP-Win32 Driver Version 9.9 
Sat Aug 11 02:53:59 2012 TAP-Win32 MTU=1500
Sat Aug 11 02:53:59 2012 Notified TAP-Win32 driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 1.2.4.6/255.255.255.252 on interface {3A817AE1-696B-4DEB-BD4F-8BE01F11FC47} [DHCP-serv: 1.2.4.5, lease-time: 31536000]
Sat Aug 11 02:53:59 2012 Successful ARP Flush on interface [25] {3A817AE1-696B-4DEB-BD4F-8BE01F11FC47}
Sat Aug 11 02:54:01 2012 TEST ROUTES: 2/2 succeeded len=1 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Sat Aug 11 02:54:01 2012 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 5.34.244.*** MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1
 OK!
Sat Aug 11 02:54:01 2012 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 1.2.4.5
 OK!
Sat Aug 11 02:54:01 2012 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 1.2.4.5
 OK!
Sat Aug 11 02:54:01 2012 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 1.2.4.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 1.2.4.5
 OK!
Sat Aug 11 02:54:01 2012 Initialization Sequence Completed
Sat Aug 11 03:53:56 2012 TLS: soft reset sec=0 bytes=429941/0 pkts=4470/0
Sat Aug 11 03:54:00 2012 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=Fort-Funston/OU=changeme/CN=macvpn/name=changeme/emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Sat Aug 11 03:54:00 2012 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=Fort-Funston/OU=changeme/CN=Build_Diffie_Hellman/name=changeme/emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Sat Aug 11 03:54:02 2012 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Sat Aug 11 03:54:02 2012 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 11 03:54:02 2012 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Sat Aug 11 03:54:02 2012 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 11 03:54:02 2012 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
Sat Aug 11 04:34:50 2012 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Sat Aug 11 04:34:50 2012 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe DELETE 1.2.4.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 1.2.4.5
 OK!
Sat Aug 11 04:34:50 2012 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe DELETE 5.34.244.*** MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1
 OK!
Sat Aug 11 04:34:50 2012 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe DELETE 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 1.2.4.5
 OK!
Sat Aug 11 04:34:50 2012 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe DELETE 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 1.2.4.5
 OK!
Sat Aug 11 04:34:50 2012 Closing TUN/TAP interface
Sat Aug 11 04:34:50 2012 SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
Sat Aug 11 04:39:00 2012 OpenVPN 2.2.2 Win32-MSVC++ [SSL] [LZO2] [PKCS11] built on Dec 15 2011
Sat Aug 11 04:39:07 2012 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Sat Aug 11 04:39:07 2012 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Sat Aug 11 04:39:07 2012 LZO compression initialized
Sat Aug 11 04:39:07 2012 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1576 D:140 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Sat Aug 11 04:39:07 2012 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Sat Aug 11 04:39:07 2012 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1576 D:1450 EF:44 EB:135 ET:32 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Sat Aug 11 04:39:07 2012 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '2547efd2'
Sat Aug 11 04:39:07 2012 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '77cf0943'
Sat Aug 11 04:39:07 2012 Attempting to establish TCP connection with 5.34.244.***:443
Sat Aug 11 04:39:08 2012 TCP connection established with 5.34.244.***:443
Sat Aug 11 04:39:08 2012 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Sat Aug 11 04:39:08 2012 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: 5.34.244.***:443
Sat Aug 11 04:39:08 2012 TLS: Initial packet from 5.34.244.***:443, sid=c86d779b e406746d
Sat Aug 11 04:39:08 2012 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Sat Aug 11 04:39:12 2012 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=Fort-Funston/OU=changeme/CN=macvpn/name=changeme/emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Sat Aug 11 04:39:12 2012 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=Fort-Funston/OU=changeme/CN=Build_Diffie_Hellman/name=changeme/emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Sat Aug 11 04:39:14 2012 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Sat Aug 11 04:39:14 2012 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 11 04:39:14 2012 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Sat Aug 11 04:39:14 2012 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 11 04:39:14 2012 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
Sat Aug 11 04:39:14 2012 [Build_Diffie_Hellman] Peer Connection Initiated with 5.34.244.***:443
Sat Aug 11 04:39:16 2012 SENT CONTROL [Build_Diffie_Hellman]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Sat Aug 11 04:39:16 2012 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222,dhcp-option DNS 4.2.2.1,route 1.2.4.1,topology net30,ping 5,ping-restart 30,ifconfig 1.2.4.6 1.2.4.5'
Sat Aug 11 04:39:16 2012 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Sat Aug 11 04:39:16 2012 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Sat Aug 11 04:39:16 2012 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Sat Aug 11 04:39:16 2012 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Sat Aug 11 04:39:16 2012 ROUTE default_gateway=192.168.1.1
Sat Aug 11 04:39:16 2012 TAP-WIN32 device [Local Area Connection 2] opened: \\.\Global\{3A817AE1-696B-4DEB-BD4F-8BE01F11FC47}.tap
Sat Aug 11 04:39:16 2012 TAP-Win32 Driver Version 9.9 
Sat Aug 11 04:39:16 2012 TAP-Win32 MTU=1500
Sat Aug 11 04:39:16 2012 Notified TAP-Win32 driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 1.2.4.6/255.255.255.252 on interface {3A817AE1-696B-4DEB-BD4F-8BE01F11FC47} [DHCP-serv: 1.2.4.5, lease-time: 31536000]
Sat Aug 11 04:39:16 2012 Successful ARP Flush on interface [25] {3A817AE1-696B-4DEB-BD4F-8BE01F11FC47}
Sat Aug 11 04:39:18 2012 TEST ROUTES: 2/2 succeeded len=1 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Sat Aug 11 04:39:18 2012 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 5.34.244.*** MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1
 OK!
Sat Aug 11 04:39:18 2012 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 1.2.4.5
 OK!
Sat Aug 11 04:39:18 2012 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 1.2.4.5
 OK!
Sat Aug 11 04:39:18 2012 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 1.2.4.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 1.2.4.5
 OK!
Sat Aug 11 04:39:18 2012 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

`ipconfig:`

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7590:fe5e:9de3:cb2d%25
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 1.2.4.6
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : WAG320N

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : WAG320N
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::607e:9cac:93a7:78d5%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:3466:31c3:fefd:fbf9
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3466:31c3:fefd:fbf9%13
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 

Tunnel adapter isatap.WAG320N:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter isatap.{3A817AE1-696B-4DEB-BD4F-8BE01F11FC47}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:102:406::102:406
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 2002:c058:6301::c058:6301

Tunnel adapter isatap.{ADF8B671-A3A2-4908-B5D0-4150F860DCDB}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : WAG320N
```

`route print` (asterisks for privacy):

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 25...00 ff 3a 81 7a e1 ......TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
 12...00 13 e8 4b 12 61 ......Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN
 11...00 1b 38 18 41 aa ......Realtek RTL8101E Family PCI-E Fast Ethernet NIC (NDIS 6.20)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 28...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.104     20
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0          1.2.4.5          1.2.4.6     31
          1.2.4.1  255.255.255.255          1.2.4.5          1.2.4.6     31
          1.2.4.4  255.255.255.252         On-link           1.2.4.6    286
          1.2.4.6  255.255.255.255         On-link           1.2.4.6    286
          1.2.4.7  255.255.255.255         On-link           1.2.4.6    286
     5.34.244.***  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.104     21
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0          1.2.4.5          1.2.4.6     31
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.104    276
    192.168.1.104  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.104    276
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.104    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.104    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link           1.2.4.6    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.104    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link           1.2.4.6    286
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 28   1140 ::/0                     2002:c058:6301::c058:6301
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 28   1040 2002::/16                On-link
 28    296 2002:102:406::102:406/128
                                    On-link
 11    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 25    286 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    276 fe80::607e:9cac:93a7:78d5/128
                                    On-link
 25    286 fe80::7590:fe5e:9de3:cb2d/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 25    286 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

UPDATE: Something strange happened. Some background first:
I use Skype to transfer files from the client machine to the machine I am using now to troubleshoot. I usually disconnect from the VPN first (with the assumption that it's not working), **however**, while sending the .txt files over to the troubleshooting machine for a recent request, I realized that it was working *while* being connected to the VPN. To make sure this wasn't a fluke, I resent a larger file, and surely enough the IP I was receiving from matched that of the VPN. This has somewhat given me hope that not all is lost. Hopefully this will shed some light on the solution to this problem.

What I **can** do:
Send files over Skype while connected to the VPN, **only** if Skype was already logged into *before* the connection the VPN was established.

What I **cannot* do:
Login/connect to Skype using the VPN.

Comment: On the client, what does `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8` give you?  Does it go through the VPN server as the first hop? Also, what OS is the client running?

Comment: The client is running Windows 7 Starter. tracert to 8.8.8.8 immediately fails. However, tracert to the server IP seems to be working. I have added the results to the bottom of the original post. @cjc

Comment: I don't care about the traceroute to the server's public IP.  The traceroute to 8.8.8.8 should traverse the VPN, given your redirect-gateway option.  So, the failure you're reporting is instructive.  Is OpenVPN running as administrator on the Windows 7 machine?  It needs admin rights to be able to change the routing table.

Comment: Sorry. Yes OpenVPN is running as administrator on the Windows 7 machine. @cjc

Comment: Your OpenVPN server IP is 1.2.4.1 across the tunnel (verify this by running `ifconfig tun0` on the server).  Can you ping that IP from the client machine?

Comment: `tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:1.2.4.1  P-t-P:1.2.4.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14788 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100`
I tried pinging both 1.2.4.1 and 1.2.4.2, but the requests time out every time. Also, upon inspecting /var/log/messages I notice I get an error message regarding IPV6 and mroute. I'll post above. @cjc

Comment: Have you tried to run `tcpdump` on the VPN server on `tun0` and your external interface? BTW a counter on your FORWARD rule is 0, the server does not seem to be forwarding anything from `tun0`. Are you sure your `sysctl.conf` has applied properly? What is an output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`?

Comment: Well the counter is 0 not only on the `tun0` forwarding rule but on the whole FORWARD chain too. It definitely is not forwarding anything, try `sysctl -p` to apply `sysctl.conf` settings.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to run tcpdump for just `tun0`. I tried `tcpdump -n tun0` but it returns a syntax error. The output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is 1. I will post the output of `sysctl -p` above (still no change after running it). @Alex

Comment: `tcpdump -i tun0` should work

Comment: If you can't ping 1.2.4.1, then the tunnel isn't really established. Look at logs on the client side. Make sure the `tun` interface in Windows has an IP address in the 1.2.4.x range.

Comment: This is strange, `tcpdump -i tun0` returns replies from the google dns server (I'm currently running `ping -t 8.8.8.8` on the client). I will post this above. @Alex The client side logs don't mention anything about failure to establish tunneling. Is there something specific I should look out for? I'll post the client-side log above.@cjc

Comment: is windows firewall on?  Why are you using a well known port (443) not that this is a problem but seems odd.  What does "route print" and "ipconfig" show on your windows client?  Does your default GW IP match your TUN address?

Comment: I've completely disabled windows firewall for the purposes of this setup. I've added the requested information above. I did, however, notice something quite strange, which I will also post above. @Kilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright guys, having some technical difficulties with my account atm, will be resolved soon hopefully. However, BIG update:

I am now able to ping/tracert to 1.2.4.1

I realized that the first rule in IPtables `POSTROUTING` was wrongly configured, so I removed it and re-added it. Everything is working as it should now! Thanks you all for your help, I would have never come across the solution without it.

@cjc @Alex @Kilo

Comment: you have two default routes with the preferred (lower metric) pointing to something other than your VPN interface.  I would fix this problem if you want all traffic to be routed over the VPN when it's up.